# Deserialization not filling data - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML .
 Sample XML is given below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>
    <TRANSACTION>
        <TRANSACTION_ID>25429</TRANSACTION_ID> 
        <MERCHANT_ACC_NO>02700701354375000964</MERCHANT_ACC_NO> 
        <TXN_STATUS>F</TXN_STATUS> 
        <TXN_SIGNATURE>a16af68d4c3e2280e44bd7c2c23f2af6cb1f0e5a28c266ea741608e72b1a5e4224da5b975909cc43c53b6c0f7f1bbf0820269caa3e350dd1812484edc499b279</TXN_SIGNATURE> 
        <TXN_SIGNATURE2>B1684258EA112C8B5BA51F73CDA9864D1BB98E04F5A78B67A3E539BEF96CCF4D16CFF6B9E04818B50E855E0783BB075309D112CA596BDC49F9738C4BF3AA1FB4</TXN_SIGNATURE2> 
        <TRAN_DATE>29-09-2015 07:36:59</TRAN_DATE> 
        <MERCHANT_TRANID>150929093703RUDZMX4</MERCHANT_TRANID> 
        <RESPONSE_CODE>9967</RESPONSE_CODE> 
        <RESPONSE_DESC>Bank rejected transaction!</RESPONSE_DESC> 
        <CUSTOMER_ID>RUDZMX</CUSTOMER_ID> 
        <AUTH_ID /> 
        <AUTH_DATE /> 
        <CAPTURE_DATE /> 
        <SALES_DATE /> 
        <VOID_REV_DATE /> 
        <REFUND_DATE /> 
        <REFUND_AMOUNT>0.00</REFUND_AMOUNT> 
    </TRANSACTION>
  </TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>
```

Following is the Class

```
[XmlType("TRANSACTION_RESPONSE")]

public class BankQueryResponse
{
    [XmlElement("TRANSACTION_ID")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MERCHANT_ACC_NO")]
    public string MerchantAccNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TXN_SIGNATURE")]
    public string TxnSignature { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
    public DateTime TranDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TXN_STATUS")]
    public string TxnStatus { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("REFUND_DATE")]
    public DateTime RefundDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RESPONSE_CODE")]
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("RESPONSE_DESC")]
    public string ResponseDesc { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("MERCHANT_TRANID")]
    public string MerchantTranId { get; set; }

}
```

The deserialization code is

```
BankQueryResponse result = new BankQueryResponse();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BankQueryResponse));

    using(TextReader xmlreader = new StringReader(responseData))
    {
        result = (BankQueryResponse) serializer.Deserialize(xmlreader);
    }
}
```

I am getting all value in result as null . I am not sure whats the reason . Can some one throws a light into the issue. Am i missing something while deserialising

Comment: The `TRANSACTION` level was lost somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify the code something like this

```
[XmlType("TRANSACTION_RESPONSE")]
public class TransactionResponse
{
    [XmlElement("TRANSACTION")]
    public BankQueryResponse Response { get; set; }

}
```

This will change like this

```
public class BankQueryResponse
{
    [XmlElement("TRANSACTION_ID")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MERCHANT_ACC_NO")]
    public string MerchantAccNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TXN_SIGNATURE")]
    public string TxnSignature { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
    public DateTime TranDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TXN_STATUS")]
    public string TxnStatus { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("REFUND_DATE")]
    public DateTime RefundDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RESPONSE_CODE")]
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("RESPONSE_DESC")]
    public string ResponseDesc { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("MERCHANT_TRANID")]
    public string MerchantTranId { get; set; }

}
```

Deseralization Code would be something like this

```
TransactionResponse result = new TransactionResponse();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionResponse));

    using(TextReader xmlreader = new StringReader(responseData))
    {
        result = (TransactionResponse) serializer.Deserialize(xmlreader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohit  . I missed one level of Hierarchy in Deserialization.  Your suggestion worked .

Comment: Its pleasure help you :)